# `Calendar` API crashes Swift Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift4, xcode9

Simple Playground:

```
import Foundation

// let c1 = Calendar.shared
let c2 = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

I've toggled between the two, and both give the same error when running the playground:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).

I am running Xcode 9 beta 2

Comment: I get same problem on 9b2, but when I try in Xcode 8.3.3 it just sits there spinning.

Comment: What's your question? Beta software is buggy! ;) You should file a bug report.

Comment: This should be a comment to the question but I lack the rep to comment. I tried this just now (c2 line) on an iPad with iOS10 and the code worked just fine. Interesting that it didn't work in Xcode. Just wanted to give a datapoint that it does work somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's working in Xcode 9.0 GM.

Like Hamish said, beta software is buggy. :)